# Erro 500 ao acessar página usando CheckSpelling no htaccess

Tags: htaccess, xampp

Tenho vários arquivos com tags de imagem, nessas imagens o nome do caminho tem letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, por exemplo:

```
<img src="../../imagens/Botoes/nomeBotao.PNG">
```

Não é possível eu alterar o nome de todas as imagens, por que têm milhares, então usei a opção `CheckSpelling` do `.htaccess` só que se eu colocar no xampp essa opção, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Erro interno do Servidor!

O servidor encontrou um erro interno e não foi possível completar sua requisição. O servidor está sobrecarregado ou existe um erro em um script CGI.

Se você acredita ter encontrado um problema no servidor, por favor entre em contato com o webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.5.27
```

Não sei como proceder, segue o arquivo .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
CheckSpelling On
```

Não sei como proceder, obrigado.

Comment: Boa tarde Furlan, coloque o conteudo do htaccess. LEIA: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - Entenda como uma critica construtiva. Assim que postar o conteudo do .htaccess eu prometo rentar responder

Comment: Obrigado por responder @GuilhermeNascimento , ja está adicionado a pergunta o código do .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `RewriteEngine On` é usado pra `mod_rewrite`, mas não há nada escrito, ou seja ele parece não fazer nada, então remova.

Já o `CheckSpelling On` é provavel que esteja desabilitado, então você deve habilitar ele no arquivo `httpd.conf`, basta procurar um lugar semelhante a este:

```apacheconf
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

E adicionar após eles isto:

```apacheconf
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
```

Em seguida reinicie o Apache (o Xampp) e teste novamente.

Comment: Obrigado @Guilherme funcionou perfeitamente!