# qualquer ficheiro .htaccess dá erro 500 como resolver?

Tags: htaccess

qualquer ficheiro .htaccess dá erro 500 como resolver?

Sempre que coloco um ficheiro .htpaccess dá sempre error este é o codigo

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   # Redirect to domain with www.
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   # Same for HTTPS:
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Aqui fala do ficheiro httpd.conf mas o meu ficheiro esta vazio

[Erro 500 ao acessar página usando CheckSpelling no htaccess](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111528/erro-500-ao-acessar-p%C3%A1gina-usando-checkspelling-no-htaccess)
Está exactamente igual como um exemplo que encontrei aqui.

Eu reinstalei o Apache2 até re-instalei o servidor e nada continua com erro 500

```
root@host:~# a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled
```

Sistema Operativo:  Ubuntu Linux 12.04.5

adicionei como é dito aqui [Erro no servidor 500 após a instalação do Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99039/erro-no-servidor-500-ap%C3%B3s-a-instala%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-laravel/99057#99057):

```
RewriteBase /
```

Não funcionou.
Tentei colocar um ficheiro .htaccess e também dá erro.

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Normalmente as informações sobre o erro são salvas no log do servidor. Verifique o log do apache e poderá saber com mais precisão do que se trata o erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi reinstalado o apache e o erro desapareceu.